# What will happened if use `if x then foo() end` to detect x is nil in Lua

Tags: lua, null, detect

I 'm not sure is it ok to use `if x then foo() end` to detect x is not nil in Lua.

There's so many detect like this in the project at hand, so I need a suggestion should I change them all or let them go.

Thanks.

Comment: It's mainly going to come down to whether you're using `false` and `nil` to denote the same thing in your code or whether they serve different meanings and semantics in the context of your project. If it's the former I wouldn't bother changing it.

Answer (score 2):

An expression is considered false, for the purposes of any condition statement, on exactly two conditions: the expression is the boolean value `false` or the expression is `nil`.

So `if x then foo() end` will call `foo` if `x` is neither `nil` nor `false`. If you want to restrict it to `nil` only (and you usually don't), then use `x ~= nil`.